# How to create a secondary window in the Hololens using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, hololens

I am trying to develop an app for the Hololens using HTML adn Javascript. How can I create a secondary window in this app? I would like to display pictures in a secondary window. (If you click on a picture in the app, a secondary window should appear with this picture in it. The window should be scaleable and moveable.)

Comment: What other requirements do you have? Is that all you need or should it also use particles and networking?

Comment: This all that I need. I am new to the Hololens system. Would be fine if you could help me.